# Prevent Explorer from customizing details columns for images and audio files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I don't want Windows Explorer to customize its detail columns automatically when the directory has images or audio files. I want the old-school look of just file name, size, type, date modified. I have to set this up manually every time. How can I lock this in for all directories once and for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but it is worth a shot. This should set all Explorer windows back to the old school style you want.

IN regedit navigate to the following key
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell

and then change the value for "FolderType" from whatever it is to "NotSpecified".
Log off and back on and things should be as you wanted.

Comment: Absolutely right on.
I had to add the string value.